# Set "fill" and "stroke" opacity independently in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Is there a way to create a transparent rectangle with opace border in Inkscape?
It looks like the "Fill" and "Stroke" of the object are affected by a single "Opacity" control. Isn't there a way?

Inkscape version is 0.48.3.1 r9886.

P.S. I've found [this thread](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=6318) in Inkscape forum which is not exactly on topic, but there I read that what I'm trying to do is not at all a problem for Inkscape 0.48. What am I missing?

Comment: You did notice that "A" (like "Alpha") slider underneath the color sliders?

Comment: Hell if I did! :) That solves it, but what's the point of the opacity control then?

Comment: Defining an overall opacity for *any* object, not just certain areas/colors. If you hang with me a minute, I'll make a pictured guide. ;)

Comment: Sure, if you feel like it :) The question could use an accepted answer. In the meantime, thanks for opening my eyes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is such a possibility. Every color within Inkscape has four components:

- **R** ed
- **G** reen
- **B** lue
- **A** lpha

Alpha is basically that transparency of this color and this color alone. While the Opacity is Object-wide.

[image: An image showing the, german, sorry, Inkscape with some very poor drawings and explanations.]

The difference between transparency of one color and overall opacity is that parts of an object can shine through other parts of the same object. The second row in the picture displays this nicely, as the background shines through the border. This is not the case if you set the overall opacity.

Anyway, you're looking for the fourth slider in the Object-Properties dialog which is labeled "A".

*And sorry for the german interface...*

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Bobby's answer (https://superuser.com/a/417553/106977), Opacity can be applied either a group or individual objects inside that group, versus the Alpha cannot. See the two screenshots below: In the upper one, I've selected the group called "group_of_stuff", but in the lower one, I've selected the rectangle called "some_rect".

[image]